# Impossible to use dark background in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have discovered some problems when I run a page with dark background and image element with some white borders in IE8. The problems is that a white flicker and flash apperas in the top, middle or bottom part of the image when reloading or load another page. I have serched a lot and found a kinds of code to put inside of meta tags, but nothing works for me. Is it really that bad, that a dark background and white borders create this problems in IE and there is nothing to do? Or what could I do to get rid of this flicker and flashes?

Comment: Any way to show us a screenshot or example code?

Comment: Do you have a live example we can see? Hard to tell what you're talking about.

Comment: Could you maybe send a screenshot or screen recording? I do not understand what you mean. Besides - it's normal to see the browser drawing and redrawing the page while it's loading. In fact, it's recommended to have this kind of "feedback", otherwise the user will think that the loading has frozen and will try refreshing the page (which will start it all over and eventually they'll just give up).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not ready with the page yet. I have to come back when it's ready. When you google the net like "ie background flicker" there are a lot of subjects about this problem. I hope you know what i mean with this flicker and flashing. I see a white background very fast before the dark background is back. There is no problem in Firefox or Chrome. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think that it would be is a [resurrected IE6 bug](http://evil.che.lu/2006/09/25/no-more-ie6-background-flicker).

Have you tried fixing that and seeing if that works?

Comment: It seems like this is working, but it's strange that it's working on IE8!? Thanks!

Comment: @user637364 Not really, they never fix bugs. *rolls eyes*